# Cannot drop table users because other objects depend on it

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-drop, drop-table

I want to drop my tables in my database.
But, when I use, for example,
`DROP TABLE if exists users;`
I receive this message:

> cannot drop table users because other objects depend on it

I found the solution is to drop all tables. But, anyway, how to solve this problem without total data removal?

Comment: basing on Foreign Key constraints you need to delete basing on condition

Comment: Put some more thought into what you are doing.  Start with justifying the need to drop the table in the first place.

Comment: Delete from Table2 t where t.Col1 in  ( Select 1 from table1 tt where tt.col1 = t.col1 ) after deleting now drop the table which you want to delete

Comment: @mohan111: _deleting_ the rows in the referencing table won't help at all. The foreign key needs to be dropped.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Use the `cascade` option:

```
DROP TABLE if exists users cascade;
```

this will drop any foreign key that is referencing the `users` table or any view using it.

It will not drop other *tables* (or delete rows from them).

Comment: Will it drop lines in other tables that depends on the user?

Comment: @PaulinTrognon: no, it only drops the foreign key constraints referencing that table and the table itself, nothing else will be deleted or dropped

Comment: It will also drop any views that reference your table.

Comment: It actually dropped both tables in my case so be aware. I believe this happened because I created the second table by inheriting from the first!

Comment: @tito.300: inheritance is something different than foreign key references.

Comment: Thats right, Hopefully, others that get this error `cannot drop table users because other objects depend on it` do not make the same mistake before checking what the constraint is. Just wanted to share

Comment: it worked for me. I used
"DROP VIEW if exists my_view cascade;"

Answer (score 25):

If it was really necessary to drop that specific table with or without recreating it, then first find the object(s) that depends on it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW admin.v_view_dependency AS 
SELECT DISTINCT srcobj.oid AS src_oid
  , srcnsp.nspname AS src_schemaname
  , srcobj.relname AS src_objectname
  , tgtobj.oid AS dependent_viewoid
  , tgtnsp.nspname AS dependant_schemaname
  , tgtobj.relname AS dependant_objectname
FROM pg_class srcobj
  JOIN pg_depend srcdep ON srcobj.oid = srcdep.refobjid
  JOIN pg_depend tgtdep ON srcdep.objid = tgtdep.objid
  JOIN pg_class tgtobj ON tgtdep.refobjid = tgtobj.oid AND srcobj.oid <> tgtobj.oid
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace srcnsp ON srcobj.relnamespace = srcnsp.oid
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace tgtnsp ON tgtobj.relnamespace = tgtnsp.oid
WHERE tgtdep.deptype = 'i'::"char" AND tgtobj.relkind = 'v'::"char";
```

Then,

```
select top 99 * from admin.v_view_dependency where src_objectname like '%the_table_name_it_complaint_about%';
```

The result set will show you the dependant object in the field "dependant_objectname".

Answer (score 5):

In general, to drop several interdependent tables you start from the tables that nothing depends on (the ones that have foreign keys pointing *to* other tables), and work backwards. E.g., if the table `transactions` depends on the table `users`, you'd drop `transactions` first. In short: Delete tables in the reverse order from how they were created.

If you manage to create tables with circular dependencies, you can first delete the foreign key constraint that prevents deletion. Or you can use the modifier `CASCADE`, which (as @a_horse explained in the comments), will drop any foreign key constraints that involve the deleted table. But note that not all DBMS's support `CASCADE`: Postgres does, but MySQL does not (the keyword is accepted but has no effect).

Comment: "*needs to check and modify each and every record with a foreign key*" - this is plain wrong. The `cascade` option does **not** check all rows in the referencing tables - it simply drops the foreign keys. It does not delete any data.

Comment: I was going by your description: To "drop a foreign key that is using the users table", you need to modify the record containing the foreign key. But actually [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-droptable.html) suggests that the entire child table is dropped, not just the record or the key: "Automatically drop objects that depend on the table (such as views)." Can you clarify?

Comment: the dependent object in this case is the foreign key constraint **not** the table. `drop table ... cascade` will not delete any rows in other tables and will not drop any other table than the one mentioned in the DDL statement. See here for a proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d258/1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Corrected.

Comment: If you drop a database-user with 'cascade' option it will drop all dependend objects. For example all tables which the user owns (and all data in these tables). So it is possible to unexpectedly loose all data and schema when using 'cascade'.

Comment: @Alex, are you referring to deleting a database user, or to dropping a regular table named `users` that other tables refer to through foreign keys? The question is about the second case, and as [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d258/1) posted by a_horse_with_no_name proves, cascade-deleting a table does _not_ delete other tables with foreign key references. (Read `table users` for `table one` in the fiddle.)

Comment: I'm referring to deleting a database user (not a table). Just wanted to point out that it is not always "safe" to use 'cascade' keyword. I used to think that if the database compains all I have to do is to add the 'cascade' keyword and the database will do what I want to be done. It worked until one day i tried to drop a database user :-P

Answer (score 0):

use the following command :

```
drop trigger "trigger_name" on "table_name";
```

as per the supabase documentation [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/postgres/triggers#dropping-a-trigger).

Answer (score 0):

I created `my_func()` trigger function as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I created `my_t` trigger with `my_func()` on `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_t AFTER UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION my_func();
```

Then, I tried to drop `my_func()` trigger function as shown below:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION my_func;
```

But, I got the similar error below:

> ERROR:  cannot drop function my_func() because other objects depend on it
> DETAIL:  trigger my_t on table test depends on function my_func()
> HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

So, I set `CASCADE` as shown below, then I could drop `my_func` trigger function and `my_t` trigger together without error. *[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropfunction.html) explains how to drop a function in detail:

```sql
                   -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
DROP FUNCTION my_func CASCADE;
```

Or first, I dropped `my_t` trigger on `test` table as shown below. *[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptrigger.html) explains how to drop a trigger in detail::

```sql
DROP TRIGGER my_t ON test;
```

Then, I could drop `my_func()` trigger function without error as shown below:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION my_func;
```