# Changing primary_key to Django AbstractBaseUser model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-migrations, django-users, django-custom-user

I have this custom `User` model in which I've changed the primary_key to `email` field like so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # Primary Key of my model 
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)   

    username = models.CharField(_('username'),max_length=30,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.ñ@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,         null=True,
    )

    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,            null=True,)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.')

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = UserManager()
```

I also have another model named `Match`:

```
class Match(models.Model):

    match_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    home_team_players_accept = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='home_team_players_accept',
        blank=True,)

    away_team_players_accept = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='away_team_players_accept',
        blank=True,)

    home_team_players_cancel = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='home_team_players_cancel',
        blank=True,)

    away_team_players_cancel = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='away_team_players_cancel',
        blank=True,)

    fichaje_players_match = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='fichaje_players_match',
        blank=True,)
```

When I execute `python manage.py migrate` I get this output:

```
File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/fuupbol2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.InternalError: cannot drop constraint auth_user_pkey on table auth_user because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint auth_user_groups_user_id_6a12ed8b_fk_auth_user_username on table auth_user_groups depends on index auth_user_pkey
constraint auth_user_user_permissio_user_id_a95ead1b_fk_auth_user_username on table auth_user_user_permissions depends on index auth_user_pkey
constraint games_information_match__user_id_246b2ea3_fk_auth_user_username on table games_information_match_away_team_players_cancel depends on index auth_user_pkey
constraint games_information_match__user_id_9d9f8df1_fk_auth_user_username on table games_information_match_home_team_players_cancel depends on index auth_user_pkey
constraint games_information_match__user_id_79122347_fk_auth_user_username on table games_information_match_fichaje_players_match depends on index auth_user_pkey
constraint games_information_match__user_id_54e7681b_fk_auth_user_username on table games_information_match_away_team_players_accept depends on index auth_user_pkey
constraint games_information_match__user_id_14203632_fk_auth_user_username on table games_information_match_home_team_players_accept depends on index auth_user_pkey
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

I've found some references about this scenario case, but I don't understand how to address this inconvenience

[Renaming a primary key fails "cannot drop constraint on table because other objects depend on it"](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27267)

[Cannot drop table users because other objects depend on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338711/cannot-drop-table-users-because-other-objects-depend-on-it)

I even tried dropping the whole database, but the inconvenience persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder `migrations` of your project, there are some files named like so:

```
0001_initial.py
0002_auto_ ... .py etc.
```

those files are the history of your database migrations and since you just dropped your database I will assume that you don't need the migration history.

Therefore, the simple solution is to clear your `migrations` folder (delete everything **except** the `__init__.py` file), drop your database once more and:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Good luck :)